# How can I change the screen resolution on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, resolution, screen

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed alonside windows in dual-boot.
After installing the latest nvidia drives (304.64 I believe) the resolution dropped to 600x480 and it's the only option available in the display menu in Unity.

My monitor's resolution is 1360x768, how can I chage the resolution to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For get higher resolution in ubuntu 12.4 refer this - http://ab-webs.blogspot.in/2013/01/ubuntu-shows-only-800600-resolution-in.html

Answer (score 0):

My wife's profile was doing something very similar (resolution was smaller than it should be and I couldn't fixed it through system settings). I executed `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` and logged and back in and it was fixed.

I haven't seen any negative effects, but if you decide to do this realize it might scramble something else. I don't know what else might use this file.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm waaaaay late to party, but here is my answer:

If you can't change screen resolution from display menu, try changing it from Terminal! *(Command-Line)*.

You can achieve this by running these commands:

Enumerate the names of all your video outputs, and the possible resolutions for those currently connected to a monitor:

```
xrandr -q
```

Choose the name of the output you wish to change the resolution of, and:

```
xrandr --output <OUTPUT> --mode 1024x768
```

**Note:** *If running from a text terminal, that is not running in gfx environment, you'll have to add a `-d :0` parameter, i.e:*

```
xrandr -d :0 -q
xrandr -d :0 --output <OUTPUT> --mode 1024x768
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/398740/1103062)